# Easy method of translating web application. [cake_php]

Tags: cakephp, localization

I'm writing a web-based computer game (mainly cakephp, some js only for ui). I need to setup another instantion in other language, and for this I need translations. I translated whole project line-by-line, but this generates problem during bug fixes, also both versions require separate svn repo. I don't want to use gettext, because i have very limited server resources, and I don't want to do this live, during execution. They are separate instances anyway, so I need rather a parser that generates copy of a template project depending on file woth translations. Otherwise i will have to write it myself. Anybody knows such a program?

Comment: Gettext has practically no effect in performance.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you didn't read the [Internationalization & Localization](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) chapter on cakephp manual.